# javascript find matching variables between two nested arrays

Tags: javascript

I have two nested arrays.

```
arr1 = [["image1","shirt", "collared",40],["image3","shirt", "buttoned",40]]
arr2 = [["image1","blue"],["image2","red"]]
```

The desired output is : If the image names (`image`) match, I want to return the color from the second array to a variable.

I have tried using two for loops:

```
var color = for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++ ) {
for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++ ) {
if (arr1[i][0] === arr2[j][0]) {
return arr2[j][1]
}
}
```

Since this is a larger part of a program, The first loop gets executed much before the second loop...however both are nested into each other in the order that I have specified.....I am trying to using the variable to color some html elements, but my entire program gets halted.  I am not sure if my approach is right.

Comment: you can not return from a loop and set a variable.

Comment: You missed a quote before `blue`: `["image1",blue"]`. This should be a typo...

Comment: @FZs you can suggest an edit

Comment: @epascarello  How could I return the color from the second arr?

Comment: @Adelin For one quote?

Comment: @Apricot I do not even know what the outcome is supposed to be....

Comment: Why are you not assigning the value of colour when you have a match instead of trying to return it. Just do `colour = arr2[j][1]`

Comment: I came this far before they posted reduces: `const images1 = JSON.stringify(arr1).match(/image\d/g);
    const images2 = JSON.stringify(arr2).match(/image\d/g);
    const same = images1.filter(element => images2.includes(element));
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feels like you're trying to use the second array as a lookup into the first. Here's a way to do this by transforming it into an object:

```
 function toLookupTable(shirtColors) {

     //keys will be image names, values will be colors
     const lookupTable = {};

     shirtColors.forEach(shirtColor => {
         //use array destructuring
         const [ image, color ] = shirtColor;
         lookupTable[image] = color;
     });
     return lookupTable;
 }

 const colorLookup = toLookupTable( [["image1","blue"],["image2","red"]] );

 console.log(colorLookup["image2"]); //outputs "red"
```

Comment: personally I would have just used reduce.

Comment: Yeah, I find reduce can be quite hard-to-read and intimidating for novices. Could also have done it easily with lodash.

Answer (score 1):

Use Array#reduce and Array#findIndex

> I want to return the color from the second array to a variable.

```js
const arr1 = [["image1","shirt", "collared",40],["image3","shirt", "buttoned",40]]
const arr2 = [["image1", "blue"],["image2","red"]]

const res = arr2.reduce((a,[image,color])=>{
   if(arr1.findIndex(([n])=>n===image) > -1) a.push(color);
   return a;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let arr1 = [["image1","shirt", "collared",40],["image3","shirt", "buttoned",40]];
let arr2 = [["image1","blue"],["image2","red"]];

let op = arr1.reduce((out,inp,index)=>{
  if(arr2[index].includes(inp[0])){
    out.push(arr2[index][1])
  }
  return out
},[] )

console.log(op)
```